# Is it possible to use std::array as a hash_table value, but with different size

Tags: c++, arrays, caching, memory, hashmap

I have a large data in RAM, where for each user there are several unsigned short (2 bytes) values. Their amount is ranged from 0 to 256, but the real case is that I have 12M users with just 1 value, 6M with 2, 3.5M with 3 etc. up to 1 user with 60 values.

I need to choose a datatype that would be memory, access and modification-efficient. I wanted to use vector for such a purpose, but the size of the empty vector itself is 24 bytes. This is too much for my RAM.

Now I want to use std::array<>, because it doesn't allocate any additional bytes except the space for the data inside, i.e.

```
sizeof(std::array<unsigned short, 3>) // 6UL
sizeof(std::vector<unsigned short>) + sizeof(unsigned short) * v.capacity() // 24UL + 6UL
```

The problem is that **std::array must specify the size on compile time**. As you could guess, I can't do it. **Is there a workaround?** I store my users in hast_table<unsigned int, T>. Can I, for example, store arrays with different size for each key?

Comment: Can't be done without playing games that'll probably push you back up into `vector` memory consumption territory. You could allocate the maximum possible size for all, but that's also a huge waste. You're going to have to do something custom, I think.

Comment: The size of a `std::array` is part of it's type, so you can't have different size arrays as part of a hash table. Have you considered `std::unique_ptr<unsigned short[]>`?

Comment: Or your own vector like class but with something like *short string optimization* to avoid heap allocation for short vectors.

Comment: @user4581301 can you give me a hint where I can start searching for that custom type. I have no ideas

Comment: @vamirio-chan You don't search for a custom type, by definition you write it yourself. Think about what you need (a vector with a smaller overhead) and start coding it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No. I am afraid it does not work with different size!

Comment: While this is true, the asker can't have varying sizes of `array`s, there will be work-arounds.